# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)の解決法(python3.7)

Tags: python, python3

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from optimizer import SGD
from trainer import Trainer
import numpy as np
from two_layer_net import TwoLayerNet

max_epoch = 4395
batch_size = 500
hidden_size = 2000
learning_rate = 1.0

x,t = np.genfromtxt(fname="1ghdenn.csv",encoding='UTF-8',dtype=None,delimiter='\t')
model = TwoLayerNet(input_size = 4395,hidden_size = hidden_size,output_size = 24)
optimizer = SGD(lr = learning_rate)

trainer = Trainer(model,optimizer)
trainer.fit(x,t,max_epoch,batch_size,eval_interval = 10)
trainer.plot()
```

このコードを打つとタイトルのようなエラーが出てきます。
どなたか解決法をご教授願います。

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\卒業研究２\1G\NN3.py", line 13, in <module>
    x,t = np.genfromtxt(fname="1ghdenn.csv",encoding='UTF-8',dtype=None,delimiter='\t')
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)より詳しいエラーです

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、そちらを利用頂ければと思います :)

Answer (score 2):

"unpack" というのは「[シーケンスのアンパック](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)」のことであり、今回のエラーは「`np.genfromtxt()` 関数の返り値を `x, t = np.genfromtxt(なんとかかんとか)` という形で 2 つの変数にアンパックして代入しようとしているけど、右辺をアンパックすると 2 つより多くなってしまうよ」という意味です。

[`np.genfromtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) 関数の返り値は NumPy array なので、基本的には今回のような書き方ではなく、一度 array として変数に受け取って、それから加工する形が一般的だと思います。

```
data = np.genfromtxt(なんとかかんとか)
```